# php timestring() fails to return correct result 4:00 PM

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

**GOAL:** Add X amount of seconds to existing time stamp (H:i:s) and convert it into a human readable non-military (24:00 Hr) **AM/PM time stamp** ('3:15 pm'). IF possible, I want to nix the leading zero in instances where timestamp would otherwise read '03:15'.

**PROBLEM:** All tests return the same results adjusting for variable time added return the same final result: 16:00:00 and/or 04:00 pm

**THE ASK:** Guidance on where / how my code is failing and how to correct it. I have googled and searched stack, etc. I have run experiments for a few hours and I always get the same result regardless of variables I feed into the test. I have attempted 23 tests and continually returned the same result.

**ENVIRONMENT:** MAMP, PHP 8.1, Bootstrap

**CURRENT RESULT:**
01:43:21
1652258601
1652258807
16:00:00 PM
4:00 PM

**THE CODE:**

```
$myTIME = '01:43:21';
$staging .= $myTIME . '<br>';

$this_time = strtotime($myTIME);
$staging .= $this_time . '<br>';

$add = rand(23, 218);
$stamp = $this_time + $add;

$staging .= $stamp . '<br>';
$staging .= date("H:i:s A", strtotime($stamp)) . '<br>';

#   $stamp = '23:00'; $stamp = new DateTime($stamp); echo $dt->format('h:i A');
$est = date('h:i:s', strtotime($stamp));

$staging .= date( 'g:i A', strtotime( $stamp ) );
```

Comment: `$stamp` is already a timestamp, so `strtotime($stamp)` fails and returns false, and `$est` does not contain what you expect it to.

Comment: Thank you @aynber. I have made the changes you suggested and it fixed everything. I'm still new and find timestamps a little vexing so I clearly have more reading to do on the subject. Thank you very much for you succinct guidance and help

Comment: Is there a way for me to flag your answer as the correct answer so you get the points @anyber or if you post it as an answer I will flag it as the accepted answer. Thanks your very awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$stamp` is already an integer/timestamp, so `strtotime($stamp)` fails. Take that off, and the date will format correctly.

```
$est = date('h:i:s', $stamp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is a very much appreciated.